# Will changing the RSA Padding in OpenSSL cause issues?

Tags: rsa, padding, padding-oracle

I'm currently looking at changing the padding type from one of the Oracle Padding attacks to a secure one. Would this break data already encrypted using the old method?

Comment: Mainly out of curiosity, which padding mode would you be changing from and to which mode?

Comment: Presumably PKCS#1v1.5 to OAEP.

Comment: To make matters worse, if you still support the old vulnerable algorithm, you'd probably still be vulnerable to padding oracles, even for data that was encrypted using the new algorithm as long as you use the same RSA key for both.

Comment: @CodesInChaos you would be correct. And thanks for the awesome answer you had.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every RSA padding I'm familiar with is incompatible with the other schemes.